# How to justified enumerate texts in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to justify or align all the three phrases. How can I do that?

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle[alignment=center]{Problema de Pesquisa} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\begin{enumerate}
\item Será que as escolhas dos diferentes indivíduos acontecem de forma racional? \vspace{0.5cm}
\item É possível que os mercados ajudem as pessoas a obterem um estado de satisfação melhor? \vspace{0.5cm}
\item Compreender a dinâmica dos mercados através dos consumidores e investidores é de suma importância para o desenvolvimento de uma sociedade. 

\end{enumerate}


\end{frame}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ragged2e` package provides the command `\justifying`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Problema de Pesquisa}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \justifying
    \setlength\itemsep{0.5cm}
    \item Será que as escolhas dos diferentes indivíduos acontecem de forma racional?
    \item É possível que os mercados ajudem as pessoas a obterem um estado de satisfação melhor?
    \item Compreender a dinâmica dos mercados através dos consumidores e investidores é de suma importância para o desenvolvimento de uma sociedade. 
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```